# Change labels in R shiny/ggvis plot

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I need to have with *ggvis* in *shiny* the **labels=** axis feature.

In R the **labels** axis argument allow to change the x labels (adding a Kb format), that keep the order and the relative distance between items:

```
mtcars <- mtcars[1:10, ]
my_data <- mtcars[order(mtcars$disp),]
xpos <- sort(mtcars$disp)
plot(my_data$disp, my_data$mpg, type = "l", xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=xpos, labels=sprintf("%.2fKb", xpos/10))
```

With this we get what we need:

[image]

Now we try to get the exact same on shiny with ggvis:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
mtcars
ui <- pageWithSidebar( div(),
                       sidebarPanel(uiOutput("plot_ui"),width=2),
                                    mainPanel(ggvisOutput("plot"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    mtc <- reactive({
        my_data <- mtcars[1:10, ]
        # Do some sorting/ordering if you want (here sorted by disp)
        my_data <- my_data[order(my_data$disp), ]
        my_labels <- c(as.character(paste0((my_data$disp)/1000, "Kb")))
        y <- my_data$mpg
        x <- factor(c(my_data$disp), labels = c(unique(my_labels)))
        data.frame(x = x, y = y)
    })

   mtc %>%
   ggvis(~x,~y ) %>%
   layer_lines() %>%
   add_axis("x", properties=axis_props(labels=list(fontSize = 10))) %>%
   bind_shiny("plot", "plot_ui")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

As we highlight in red, the distances are not correct. So how can we have on shiny the same plot we have on plain R with **axis(label=...** ?

Comment: Why do you use ggvis instead of plot in your observer? Is this question related to axis in ggvis?

Comment: Yes it's probably a ggvis axis question, I updated tags

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I fiddled around with it and you have to convert your x-axis into a `factor` first. I've added some sorting to the `dataframe` as you probably want these to be in order also (you can easily remove it otherwise). You can put labels on the axis yourself. Let me know if you have any questions. Also I changed the data on the x-axis to display `mtcars$disp` as it has values in 100s

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)
mtcars
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  div(),
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("n", "Number of points", min = 1, max = nrow(mtcars),value = 10, step = 1),
    uiOutput("plot_ui"),width=2),
  mainPanel(ggvisOutput("plot"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mtc <- reactive({ 
    my_data <- mtcars[1:input$n, ] 
    # Do some sorting/ordering if you want (here sorted by disp)
    my_data <- my_data[order(my_data$disp),]
    my_labels <- c(as.character(paste0((my_data$disp)/1000,"Kb")))
    y <- my_data$mpg
    x <- factor(c(my_data$disp), labels=c(unique(my_labels)))
    data.frame(x = x, y = y)
  })

  mtc %>%
    ggvis(~x,~y ) %>%
    layer_lines() %>%
    add_axis("x", properties=axis_props(labels=list(fontSize = 10))) %>%
    bind_shiny("plot", "plot_ui")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Updated Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: 11.20Kb 13.75Kb 8.20Kb 17.15Kb 19.40Kb 19.60Kb 20.70Kb 16.90Kb 16.50Kb

Comment: It's what we try at first but the numeric order is not kept. For example if you replace `my_data <- mtcars[1:input$n, ]` by  `my_data <- mtcars[1:input$n, ] * 10 - 15` X axis will be in this order  11.20Kb 13.75Kb 8.20Kb 17.15Kb 19.40Kb 19.60Kb 20.70Kb 16.90Kb 16.50Kb

Comment: This isn't clear to me at all, why do you need to multiply your date by 10 and subtract 15?

Comment: Is to illustrate that wt data values `c(89, 99, 100, 200, 324)` have a mixed order after the transformation e.g. :  `c(100k, 200k, 324k, 89k, 99k)`

Comment: I edited my original question to add the image of what we get wrong, the only modification to your server function was `my_data <- mtcars[1:input$n, ] * 10 - 15`